# Flutter firebase phone login doesn't work on real iOS device but works on simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, dart

I've developed an app with a phone number login feature using Firebase, and it's working flawlessly on the simulator. However, when I attempt to use it on a real iOS device, I encounter an "unknown error occurred."

[image]

I've ensured that I've added the reverse client ID to my info.plist file as required for Firebase Phone Authentication.

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!